# Delete instance of a class?

Tags: javascript

I have a class that was created like this:

```
function T() {
    this.run = function() {
        if (typeof this.i === 'undefined')
            this.i = 0;
        if (this.i > 10) {
            // Destroy this instance
        }
        else {
            var t = this;
            this.i++;
            setTimeout( function() {
                t.run();
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I initialize it like `var x = new T();`

I'm not sure how to destroy this instance from within itself once if reaches 10 iterations.

Also, I'm not sure how to destroy it externally either, in case I want to stop it before it reaches 10.

Comment: Does `delete this` work for you?

Comment: @steaks, that will do nothing

Comment: I'm not sure a class is needed in this specific case. If there's nothing more, a pure functional code would probably be cleaner.

Comment: What are you actually asking about - "delete"ing a variable (for garbage collection) or stopping the iterating? You might be asking for one thing (and getting answers for it) when you really want to do something else

Comment: This is a very over simplified version of what I have going on, trust me. I need a class.

Comment: @Ian, yes. It should stop the iteration as well as get deleted. Will overwriting window.x stop the iteration?

Comment: @VitaliyIsikov I don't think so. Try a simple example on jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fnbc9/ . I know it's a simple example, but what you do want to be "deleted"? And what do you mean by "delete"? The way I'd go about it is by setting a `stop` method on the `T` class that you can call, to stop the iteration. As for "deleting", I'm not sure, because I'm not sure of the point

Comment: Deleting is not needed really, since the global var will be overwritten very shortly after. It's stopping that iteration that I was actually having an issue with. Thanks pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @VitaliyIsikov Ahh I see. Overwriting it should dereference it, and it will be GC'ed. Well if it helps, this is how I'd set it up: http://jsfiddle.net/fnbc9/2/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To delete an instance, in JavaScript, you remove all references pointing to it, so that the garbage collector can reclaim it.

This means you must know the variables holding those references.

If you just assigned it to the variable `x`, you may do

```
x = null;
```

or

```
x = undefined;
```

or

```
delete window.x;
```

but the last one, as precised by Ian, can only work if you defined x as an explicit property of `window`.

Comment: You can only delete a variable (`x` here) if it's declared without `var`...either as a property of `window` or just without `var` :)

Comment: @VitaliyIsikov yes, that would work. The important thing is to not have the object you want to lose as value of any variable.

Comment: In the actual code the class is initialized with a variable variable, `window['request_' + request.id] = new T();`

Comment: So you may delete it in the same way : `delete window['request_' + request.id]` or `window['request_' + request.id]=null`.

Comment: @VitaliyIsikov Since you're declaring them as global properties, they will not be collected by the GC unless you dereference them (like with `delete` or `= null` like dystroy's suggesting

Comment: Delete **class** not support command and just **function** ... try javascript pure and not jQuery. Try below a posted ur code test **class**

Comment: Why does `delete`  make the variable undefined but does **not** stop any running functions of the class?

Answer (score 3):

**Class** not same function are different. Not work a delete. **Class** is system modification.

```
class SAFunc {
  method1(){
    console.log("1");
  }
  method2(){
    console.log("2");
  }
}
let func  = new SAFunc();
func['method2']()
```

Try:

- `delete window['func']` -- not work
- `delete eval['func']` -- not work
- `delete window['SAFunc']` -- not work
- ...
- ...

---

**Function** - command work delete

```
method1 = function(){
  console.log("func1");
}
function method2() {
  console.log("func2");
}
var SAFunc = { method3: function() { console.log("func3"); } }
```

Make ur test... Try:

- `delete window['method1']`
- `delete window['method2']`
- `delete SAFunc['method3']`

Good fun! i love programming

Enjoin us ;)