# How to completely erase an instance of a class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to know how to completely erase an instance of a class in Typescript, when that instance has been initiated in an array.

I have seen some answers already on how to delete instances in Javascript, and this question seems to be very close to what I am looking for: [How to destroy the instance of a JavaScript class completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384604/how-to-destroy-the-instance-of-a-javascript-class-completely), but I'm not sure if I understand it, or if it is related to my issue. I would appreciate some more detailed answer if possible (I am sort of new to Javascript/Typescript).

To give an example of what I mean, I have a class like this:

```
class Person {
  private _id: number;
  private _name: string;
  private _surname: string;
  public has_dog: boolean;

  constructor(ID:number, name:string, surname:string, has_dog:boolean) {
    this._id = ID;
    this._name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.has_dog = has_dog;
  }
```

And I am creating new instances like this:

```
let my_array: Person[];
my_array.push(new Person(123,'John', 'Smith', true));
```

Now, at some point, I might want one of those `Person` instances deleted, but I am not sure if by using `my_array.pop()` (in case I want to delete the last person) I will completely erase that instance from memory, or if it will be floating around somewhere.

If I understood everything fine, as long as that variable(instance) is not used anywhere else in the code, the garbage collector should take care of it, but I am not sure if this is correct, or if I will have some memory issues when leaving some instances "alive".

To sum up, which would be the most appropiate and effective way to delete those instances of the class from the array?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, the GC will take care of it. Just remove it from the array.

Comment: If you don't have a reference to an object, it's eligible for garbage collection. That's the case with JavaScript, since TypeScript compiles down to JS, there are no special rules regarding object removal from memory.