# Replacing instance of class will garbage collect old one?

Tags: javascript

I have a class

```
class MyClass {
....
}
```

Then I initialize an instance of that class:

```
this.myNewClass = new MyClass()
```

If I run the last command again (twice or more) and initialize a new class and assign it to `this.myNewClass` later in the future, will the previous instance be automatically garbage collected?
I'm asking because that class has listeners in it that I wouldn't want to keep running.

Also I'm seeing this answer: [Delete instance of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243463/delete-instance-of-a-class)
Which suggests settings the variable (in this case `this.myNewClass`) to undefined, is re-assigning it with a new instance the same?

Comment: As with all objects - if there are no other references to the instance, it's eligible for GC.

Comment: What are your listeners listening to? If they are registered to listen to events from some other class then that means this other class has a reference to your instance, and therefore it will not be garbage collected.

Comment: Also there is a difference between a class and an object (or instance). Your field myNewClass points to an instance of type MyClass. This instance is an object and is always a child of the class 'java.lang.Object' - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Comment: @AdriaanKoster No, objects in JavaScript are not derived from Java objects.

Comment: Thanks guys, that's a very interesting point @AdriaanKoster, those listeners are from React router browser history, so I think it makes sense they won't be removed right? As I'm researching this I see that there is a method for removing those